Matrix4x4.TRS How to change the rotation of each mesh in a Matrix4x4 List using raycast
So i have this script where i use Graphics.DrawMeshInstanced and i want to change the rotation of each mesh to align with the terrain.The problem is that i do not know how to do that cause i can not use transform.rotation for each mesh in the Matrix4x4 list.
This is how i get the "grass" objects to align with the terrain in another script where i Instantiate the grass objects manually.

            Ray ray = new Ray(treeSite + Vector3.up * 10.0f, Vector3.down); RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                allocatedGO.transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(allocatedGO.transform.up, hit.normal) * allocatedGO.transform.rotation;
            }

And below is the script i where i use Graphics.DrawMeshInstanced.
Vector3 randomPos = Random.insideUnitSphere * radius;
        randomPos += transform.position;

        float posY = terr.SampleHeight(randomPos);
        randomPos.y = posY;
        Vector3 scale = new Vector3(Random.Range(1, 1.5f), Random.Range(1, 1.5f), Random.Range(1, 1.5f));
        

        for (int i = 0; i < Instances; i++)
        {

            if (AddedMatricies < 1000)
            {
                Batches[Batches.Count - 1].Add(Matrix4x4.TRS(randomPos, Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 0), scale));
                AddedMatricies += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Batches.Add(new List<Matrix4x4>());
                AddedMatricies = 0;
            }
        }

        foreach (var Batch in Batches)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < mesh.subMeshCount; i++)
            {
                Graphics.DrawMeshInstanced(mesh, i, Materials[i], Batch);
            }
        }


Should not grass always be upright? Its not like grass and other vegetation grows at an angle just because the ground is uneven. Have you considered adding some skew instead of rotation?

It just looks better when its at a slight angle.Thank you for the comment.
